# Android SDK/NDK installation on Android

Tags: android, rust

I emulate Ubuntu on Android device using the [UserLAnd app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula&pcampaignid=APPU_1_tNmTXO3TBZDB5OUPsvWpsAI). I wanna install [android-rs-glue](https://github.com/tomaka/android-rs-glue/blob/master/README.md) to package my Rust apps as APKs, but I need Android SDK/NDK properly installed. Here's the issue:

> Install some components in the SDK:
>
> ```
> $ ./android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-18" "build-tools;26.0.1"
> ```

Result:

```sh
$ sudo . "$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager" \
        "platform-tools" \
        "platforms;android-18" \
        "build-tools;26.0.1"

# Error: Could not find or load main class 
#   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
```

I did:

```sh
$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$ANDROID_HOME/lib
```

After looking at `sdk/bin/sdkmanager` I deducted it also requires copy of `sdk/lib` as `~/lib`; then I get that:

```
Loading package information...                                                  
Loading local repository...                                                     
n% Loading local repository...        
n% Fetch remote repository...
6% Computing updates...               
8% Computing updates...               
8% Computing updates...               
10% Computing updates...              
10% Computing updates...

Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: Failed to find package platforms
```

Gonna test it further.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/tomaka/android-rs-glue/issues/177 and https://github.com/CypherpunkArmory/UserLAnd/issues/700

Answer (score 0):

- `ANDROID_HOME` should be the sdk directory, not sdk/tools dir.
- You've to specify the jar name while adding jars to classpath.

The main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli is in tools/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar. But you don't have to explicitly add it to classpath since it will be added by the `sdkmanager` script itself. You can see the jar files in tools/lib directory appended to classpath by this line in the `sdkmanager` file

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jimfs-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/repository-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/gson-2.3.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-compress-1.12.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.2.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-12.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/guava-22.0.jar
```

where `APP_HOME` is the tools dir ( android-sdk/tools/bin/.. which resolves to /android-sdk/tools/ )

So please make sure sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar exists in tools/lib directory and it contains SdkManagerCli class